# Time series difference in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, difference

I'm trying to plot the (first) difference of a time series with ggplot.
As the difference (by definition) contains one less element than the data, I (predictably) get the error message: "*Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data*".

I solved this by defining my y aesthetic as `c(NA, diff(data))` instead of just `diff(data)`, which works.
However, this feels like a clumsy workaround and only works so far as it gets me in trouble for instance when I'm trying to facet several plots. (Also, you need to keep adding NA's if a higher order of difference is needed, or more lag).

Anyone knows of a more robust solution?

The ultimate problem is this:
[What I want (this was made using patchwork::)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilMDT.png)
[What I get using faceting (NB: if I put the NA at the end, it's the third chart which becomes correct)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV9t4.png)

Comment: It's not clumsy. But its to hard to comment without seeing the whole code.

Comment: Sure. It's pretty simple though:
```
ggplot(data = data.long,
       aes(x = date,
           y = c(NA, count %>%
                 diff()
                 ),
           )
       ) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: It's not wrong, but many here would advise you to do the differencing before you create the ggplot. Piping within an aesthetic just doesn't look nice and is difficult to read.

Answer (score 4):

While adding NA to the differenced vector is not clumsy, doing this within the ggplot aesthetic is. Compare the following two code:

```
ggplot(data = data.long, aes(x = date, y = c(NA, count %>% diff()))) + 
  geom_point()
```

---

```
data.long %>%
  mutate(diff_count = c(NA, diff(count))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = diff_count)) +
    geom_point()
```

They both would give the same graph, but the second code is the preferred method since the data used for plotting (the differenced count) is calculated before being sent to ggplot and is easier to read and modify. In other words, do the data management first, then visualise the data. As you say, using the first method can get you into trouble later, for example doing more complicated graphing such as facetting.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense! However, and unfortunately, the issues stay the same (1. you need to stack up NAs if you want a higher order of differences, and 2. the faceting issue remains the same. Can't post a pic here in comments, but the (wrong) plot is exactly the same even using this more sensible code…

Comment: 1. Differencing reduces the length of the original vector by 1, or 2 etc... so to plot these together with the original data requires adding `NA`s. There's no simple workaround except to use `c(NA, ...)`. 2. You can edit your question with the pic if you think it would help.

Comment: Edward, thanks for taking the trouble. I have added the plots to the original post.

Comment: I see your problem, but I honestly cannot help without looking at your code and maybe the data, or at least a portion of it.